# MPI Programming I/O File Output

Tags: file, parallel-processing, io, mpi, binaryfiles

I am working MPI I/O. When I run code example, I am confused the output file. I think that It is a binary file.
The code is

```
//Parallel MPI I/O to a single file
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFSIZE 100
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i, myrank, buf[BUFSIZE];
MPI_File thefile;
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    for (i=0; i<BUFSIZE; i++)
        buf[i] = myrank * BUFSIZE + i;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "testfile",MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY, MPI_INFO_NULL, &thefile);
        MPI_File_set_view(thefile, myrank * BUFSIZE * sizeof(int),  MPI_INT, MPI_INT, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
        MPI_File_write(thefile, buf, BUFSIZE, MPI_INT, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_File_close(&thefile);
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

The output looks like [image]

but It should not be like this picture. I want to see integers output in my file. How can I convert to integer?

Comment: `testfile` is a binary file. `od -i testfile` will dump integers.

Comment: I got it. One more thing How can I read integers from text file. I did but when I print integers that read from file  to screen, i saw the numbers that I dont expect.

Comment: I recommend you ask an other question and clearly describe how you read integers and the discrepancy between expected and observed result.